# Why is the count of join table items so high?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, left-join

I have a Transact SQL query which returns huge values in the `Count` field.

```
SELECT max(l.Date)
      ,count(stp.Key) as 'Count'
      ,wm.Id
  FROM Web wm
  LEFT JOIN Profile stp ON wm.WebId = stp.WebId
  LEFT JOIN Log l ON wm.WebId = l.WebId
  WHERE Code = 'RR'
  GROUP By wm.Id
  ORDER BY count(stp.Key) DESC
```

If I replace the `count(stp.Key)` element with `(select count(Key) from Profile where wm.Id = Id)` then I get the real count:

```
SELECT max(l.Date)
      ,(select count(Key) from Profile where wm.Id = Id) as 'Count'
      ,wm.Id
  FROM Web wm
  LEFT JOIN Profile stp ON wm.WebId = stp.WebId
  LEFT JOIN Log l ON wm.WebId = l.WebId
  WHERE Code = 'RR'
  GROUP By wm.Id
  ORDER BY (select count(Key) from Profile where wm.Id = Id) DESC
```

For example, with the simple `count` in place the top result shows 147,000 but with the `select ...` in place it shows just 65, etc.

I believe this is because the count is counting every record in the final result set. But how do I get it to only count the `stp.Key` for the records which match the `Id` field?

**[EDIT]** As pointed out in the comments, to explain the problem...

> Table: Web

```
Id
1
2
3
```

> Table: Profile

```
Id Key
1  10
1  20
2  30
2  40
3  50
4  60
```

> Table: Log

```
Id Date
1  2022-06-12
1  2022-06-02
2  2022-06-23
2  2022-06-01
3  2022-06-14
3  2022-06-03
```

So, ultimately what I would like is a the count of rows from the Profile table for each Web record in the result set. I understand that what my original query had was simply counting the records in the final result set, but I don't understand how to get the query to count per wm.Id - that is, I want to count the related records in the joined table.

Comment: This is what happens when you have a one/many to many relationship, it is expected. If you have a table with 2 rows and `COUNT` the rows, you get `2`. if you then have another table with 6 rows, 1 row from the prior table each related to 3 of the other, you get a `COUNT` of `6` (even if you `COUNT` the same column). If you then have a table with 2 rows that you `CROSS JOIN` to, you get a `COUNT` of `12`. `COUNT` returns the number of rows (within the group/partition) within the data set, not the number of original rows. If you need a `COUNT` prior to that, `COUNT` first, then `JOIN`.

Comment: The OP is already grouping by `WM.ID`, @W_O_L_F , that won't change anything.

Comment: _I believe this is because the count is counting every record in the final result set._ Correct. There might be better ways of formulating the query but no one knows your schema, the source of column Code, how the tables are used, nor the requirements of the resultset. A guess is to logically aggregate Profile and Log separately and **then** join.

Comment: Unclear why you need to join those tables anyway. If `Code` actually comes from them then why a `LEFT JOIN` you should have an `INNER JOIN`. One option could be to put those tables into an `EXISTS` then you won't need to aggregate

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1):

try with  distinct, if stp.Key is unique

```
count(distinct stp.Key)
```

Comment: This works, but I'm not comfortable using distinct because of the innate performance problems with that keyword. (I was always taught to avoid distinct and instead use GROUP BY.)

Answer (score -2):

Try to avoid **Log** table in join that may give you the correct Result.
Use it as subquery By following way

```
    SELECT 
(select top 1 Date from Log where WebId=wm.WebId order by Date desc)
  ,count(stp.Key) as 'Count'
  ,wm.Id
FROM Web wm LEFT JOIN Profile stp ON wm.WebId = stp.WebId
WHERE Code = 'RR'
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. It does not teach and it is expressed in language that suggests uncertainty (which also implies that it is not an "answer").

Comment: @SMor Edits are made check now  and wait for minutes don't get concluded too early